# What is the special function with 4G industrial routers?

Tags: routers

Are 4G industrial routers compatible with 3G and 2G network?

Comment: Welcome to IoT StackExchange, please read the doc on how to ask good questions on the platform found here: https://iot.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask At the moment your question needs some more detail to be understood

Comment: Yes. 4G is backwards compatible to 3G, and 3G data is backward compatible to GPRS (2.5G, but it in unlikely that you will find 2G (GSM) anywhere; if you do, you would need a modem to transmit data, as GDSM had no digital transmission)

Comment: Since you posted in the IoT section, we have to assume you are asking about 4G vs 3G/2.5G for data transmissions.  As a general rule, the higher the 'G', the more speed you get.  4G is generally associated with the LTE standard, which in the right circumstances, can get you at least 1Gb/s.